# Clear both property on div that expand on hover

Tags: css, grid, hover, position

I have built a product grid.  More info is available when the product block is hovered over.  However, this expansion causes alignment issues with the other blocks.

Ideally I would like to have the blocks expand over any other blocks.  However, I think that how the first block hover behaves works (shifts the blocks below down and leave the blocks to the right as they were.

The only way I can think to achieve this is to use absolute position on each block. Really cant do that as the end goal is a cms that will generate the blocks on the fly.

Any ideas or suggestions please.

SEE AN EXAMPLE

http://tinyurl.com/mda3y3k

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to give `float` property for this situation. You just need to add an `inline-block` for your `blockcontainer` class. So replacing that with float will not require a `clear` property on hover.

I suggest you to make the below CSS changes to your classes.

```
.blockContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.blockContainer:hover {
    z-index: 100;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7wyUc/)** for the same.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change the html in your cms? If yes, Do the following changes:

**From**

```
+------------+ +--------------+ +----------------+
|            | |              | |                |
| one        | | two          | |  three         |
|            | |              | |                |
+------------+ +--------------+ +----------------+
+------------+ +--------------+ +----------------+
|            | |              | |                |
| four       | | five         | |  six           |
|            | |              | |                |
+------------+ +--------------+ +----------------+
```

**To:**

```
+------------+ +--------------+ +----------------+
|            | |              | |                |
| one        | | three        | |  five          |
|            | |              | |                |
+------------+ +--------------+ +----------------+
+------------+ +--------------+ +----------------+
|            | |              | |                |
| two        | | four         | |  six           |
|            | |              | |                |
+------------+ +--------------+ +----------------+
```

Note: The blocks one, two three ..... are divs which are displayed inline-block or floated divs. When you change you have to float left or display inline-block to your main div containing one,.... divs.